# Capture Mouse Events in WebBrowser Control (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, svg

In my app, I have a webbrowser control that displays a SVG draw, and I want to capture mouse events

It's possible to capture (via Click o MouseHover) the SVG Regions?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQ6zI.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got a excellent page explaining my own question

¡It worked for me!

[https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35373/VB-NET-C-and-JavaScript-communication]